# How should I animate the parent element's width to create a background effect?

Tags: jquery, animation, anchor

I have a `ul` for a menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">And Two</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">Then it's Three</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="#">Finally Four</a></li>
<ul>
```

When I hover over the anchors, I want a background to slide in from the left, and back out when I move the mouse away again, while the position of the text remains static. I could probably make this work easily with background images, but I thought I might be able to do it by setting the width on the `li` to 0 and the `a` to some set width, then with `jQuery` animate the width of the parent `li` on the `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        width: 270
    }, 200);
});
$('a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        width: 0
    }, 200);
});
```

When I just set the widths or set it via css, it works fine, but the slide in effect causes strange results: http://jsfiddle.net/LeonardChallis/D67dM/

My question is this: What do I need to change to make this work properly, or is there a better way to do it altogether? I don't necessarily mind the background image method, but preferably only if you can tell me why it's best and/or why other methods are worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could achieve this result by changing a few things. I now have a `mouseenter` on the `a`, and instead of a `mouseout` on the `a`, I changed it to a `mouseleave` on the `li`. I also set the `a` to `position: fixed;`.

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        width: 270
    }, 200);
});
$('li').mouseleave(function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: 0
    }, 200);
});
```

The [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeonardChallis/D67dM/39/) shows it working quite nicely.